# What is the correct way to prevent caching on ajax calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

I have an AJAX-call, which returns values from a ever changing database, based on simple standard parameters, like month of year. In IE, this function returns cached data, which it never should. I've monitored the server side, and it isn't contacted by the client.

Now, my title question has been asked in different ways, many times here already. The top two solutions are:

- set `cache: false`
- Pass a random number/string/timestamp to make the call unique.

The thing is though, that `cache: false` doesn't work, at least not in my application. On the other hand, passing a unique string to prevent caching, seems like a quick fix hack. I don't like it. So what is the correct way of preventing caching on ajax calls?

Ajax call that doesn't work in regards of preventing caching:

```
$.getJSON("myURL", {
        json : jsonDataObject,
        cache: false
    }).success(function(data) {                 
        //do something with data
});
```

I have also tried calling `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` on it's own, before the calls happen, but to no effect...

Comment: add a parameter in url with random value

Comment: Do you have control over the server endpoint? What cache headers is it returning?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, the way you think you're setting `cache` to false in your `$.getJSON()` call is incorrect. You're passing a key/value pair to the server so the request URL will look like `site.com/resource?cache=false`.

You need to make your request using the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method so you can actually set the `cache` option to `false`. However, all this does is what you call a "quick fix hack". It adds `_={current_timestamp}` to the query string so that the request will not be cached.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myurl',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: jsonDataObject,
    cache: false, // Appends _={timestamp} to the request query string
    success: function(data) {
        // data is a json object.
    }
});
```

In my opinion that's not a quick fix or a hack, it's the correct way to ensure you get a fresh response from the server.

If you'd rather not do that every time, then you can just use your own wrapper function:

```
$.getJSONUncached = function (url, data, successCallback) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        cache: false, // Appends _={timestamp} to the request query string
        success: successCallback
    });
};
```

Then you can just replace your call to `$.getJSON()` with `$.getJSONUncached()`

Comment: aaah! Now I get the difference between the $.ajax-parameters and the $.getJSON parameters. However: `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` followed by `$.getJSON(...` Should work then, shouldn't it? I see now that the use of ajaxSetup is discouraged in the documentation. I'll probably go with your example above. If it works, I'll accept the answer  :) Thanks.

Comment: Setting it globally with `$.ajaxSetup` should work, but as you found out it is discouraged and it's possible for any other script to override this so it shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: I see the answer is updated now, and It's even better than it was. I was thinking in the same lines as the wrapper function. Thank you for pointing out where my misunderstanding was, and your guidance to making it work, at the same time as I actually learnt something that will help me in the future! My problem is solved, and my ajax is not cached!

Answer (score 1):

Please let us know are you using IE8 as for that please check the below from jquery documentations

cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
Type: Boolean
If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. **The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.**

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

You don't need to false cache in your request. Use this code as a script in your head. It'll solve your caching problem. Code should like,

```
<script>$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });</script>
```

Comment: This should work. I don't know why I couldn't make it work in my case. The downside of this approach, and why I abandoned my attempts, is that it is discouraged to use $.ajaxSetup, according to the official documentation. The settings are global, and can be overwritten by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

There is HTML META TAG for cache.. I do not sure but may be useful for preventing cache.

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Comment: I have already seen this one in other answers, and it is already in my code, but it turns out it was irrelevant for my specific case.